# How to access vagrant .ivy2 directory from windows?

Tags: eclipse, windows, vagrant

I am using [Scala-IDE](http://scala-ide.org/) on Windows and my project files are in vagrant. I build project with `sbt` in vagrant and run server for testing. For deployment, I created eclipse configuration files with `sbt eclipse` and imported into Scala-IDE. My problem is when I try to run project it can't access to my `.ivy2` files because they are in vagrant home folder. How can I solve this problem ?

```
Description Resource Path Location Type Project 'test-api' is missing required library: '\home\vagrant\.ivy2\cache\com.google.guava\guava\bundles\guava-18.0.jar' test-api Build path Build Path Problem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. `sbt eclipse` command creates two files for Eclipse. They are `.classpath` and `.project`. Your `.ivy2` path is given in `.classpath` file. So firstly, I created a new folder in my vagrant directory and synced my home folder to this new folder like that. Add this to your `Vagrantfile`.

```
config.vm.synced_folder "data", "/home/vagrant"
```

Then I run `sbt eclipse` in my project folder. It created new `.classpath` files in my `data` folder. I wrote a python script which can read and replace paths in `.classpath` file. You should run this script in your project folder , it gets all sub directories and searchs `.classpath` files. Then it replaces wrong paths with correct paths.

```
    import os
    import glob

    #variables
    current_dir = "/home/vagrant/"
    dest_dir = "C:/Users/Test/Desktop/vm/data/"

    #list for directories
    filesDepth1 = glob.glob('*/')
    dirsDepth1 = list(filter(lambda f: os.path.isdir(f), filesDepth1))
    print(dirsDepth1)

    #list for files
    for directory in dirsDepth1:
            print(directory)
            root = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/" + directory
            for item in os.listdir(root):
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, item)):
                            print(item)
                            if(item == ".classpath"):
                                    FileName = root + "/" + item
                                    with open(FileName) as f:
                                            newText=f.read().replace(current_dir,dest_dir)
                                    with open(FileName, "w") as f:
                                            f.write(newText)
```